# Displaying form input instantly

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, input

I would like to know how you display directly the form input a user types in.

For example like on this site, when you ask a question, your text is shown directly at the bottom. Or like on this site http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sticky-notes-ajax-php-jquery/demo.php when you add a note, you can see on the left immediately how your sticky is going to look.

I think this is done with javascript but I don't know how

kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery.keyup events [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngWQq/19/)

```
 $("textarea").keyup(function(){
   $('div div').html(this.value);

});
$("input").keyup(function(){
   $('div span').html(this.value);

});
```

HTML

```
    <textarea ></textarea>
<input />
<div >
    <div></div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{

 position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height:100px;
}
span{

 position:absolute;
    right:3px;
    bottom:3px;
}
​
```

Comment: Instead of `keyup`, `keypress` may be a better as it also catches characters from holding down a key.

Comment: I thought for that but site he mentioned in Question has same behavior as keyup is doing.

Comment: If you're trying it with jsfiddle, be sure to click the update button if you make changes to the JavaScript. EDIT: And it's not covered by any kind of standard, it might not work with some browsers and default to only triggering on keyup.

Comment: this is great!
But how do make them different from each other? For example when I have 5 text inputs

Comment: @SamHendrickx did you means difference between textarea and div? You can decorate textarea and div as you wish using CSS.

Comment: No I mean like if I have one text input that has to appear on top of the page, and the other one at the bottom (for example)

Comment: @SamHendrickx I updated my code and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ngWQq/19/. you can decorate elements the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="example_input" type="text"/>
<div id="content_receiver">

$("#example_input").bind("keyup change", function() { 
    $("#content_receiver").html($(this).val())
})
```

Edited to respond to keyup events in addition to change events as suggested by saml

Comment: `change` only gets fired when the input loses focus with changed content.  This will not change with keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a JavaScript function is assigned to handle the `keyup` event of a form input. The function selects another element on the page and sets the `innerText` property of that element to the current value (post-keyup) of the form input.

The rest of the "preview", like the post-it note color at  http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sticky-notes-ajax-php-jquery/demo.php, or the ***text-formatting*** that you see here at SO, is done either through inline styles applied by a handler function, or by CSS, or by a combination of both.

I've set up a simple example in a fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/95nyp/1/ which emulates http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sticky-notes-ajax-php-jquery/demo.php

Please keep in mind that the reason this is not an in-depth explanation is that there are **many** ways to accomplish this, and this answer is merely one of the more simple ways.